# Setting up Dataflow with Pubsub to BigQuery gives error

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow

The error message reads. I have checked and the required API are enabled, service account is there and has Dataflow Agent role. GCS bucket is there.

```
Workflow failed. Causes: Network default is not accessible to Dataflow Service account or does not exist
```

Can someone help me please?

Comment: Can you provide more detail? What SDK + version are you using? Is your pipeline able to read from pubsub without writing to BQ? how about the other way?

Answer (score 0):

This seems like you don't have the `default` VPC network. You could confirm this on [VPC networks page](https://console.cloud.google.com/networking/networks/list). If you're using a particular VPC network or a Shared VPC network to run your Dataflow pipelines, you could check [this document](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/guides/specifying-networks#top_of_page) which explains how to specify a [network and a subnetwork in a pipeline](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/guides/specifying-networks#running_your_pipeline_with_the_network_and_subnetwork_specified).

Hope it helps.

Comment: i do have default vpc configured with 18 subnets and mode set to Auto. Does it have anything to do with firewall rules?

Comment: Yes, it could be related to firewall rules too. Since this requires to check your project's configuration, I suggest filing a case to the [GCP support team](https://cloud.google.com/support/docs/#filing_cases_via_the_support_center)